__str__ in python not respecting escape keys
So I'm learning about object oriented programming and the __str__ method, and I'm finding that when adding things to a list the formatting of the item is different to when I simply print a particular class object. Specifically, the escape keys are not being respected.
How can I maintain the formatting of the __str__ for the Student class when adding a student to the empty list in Course?
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} may enrol in this course for the following reasons:\n He is a good looking bloke \n He has matching socks'

class Course:
    def __init__(self):
        self.course = []
        self.eligible_students = ['Michael', 'Gary', 'Travis']

    def add_student_to_course(self, student):
        if student.name in self.eligible_students:
            self.course.append(str(student))
            return self.course

    def __str__(self):
        return f"The course contains these students: {self.course}"


student1 = Student('Michael', 40)
course = Course()
course.add_student_to_course(student1)
print(course)

I expected the formattting of the __str__ for the Student class to be carried over to the empty list in the Course class

When you convert a list to a string, it uses repr() rather than str() for the elements. So you need to customize __repr__()

note, you can just do __repr__ = __str__ right under your def __str__(self): ...
